# Creating arrays with Jsoup

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, jsoup

This is my first post here and I would really appreciate some help with my question! Basically, I've been trying to find a way to put every 3rd element into a separate array using Jsoup elements, but I'm stuck.

I'm making a currency converter and want three arrays: one with the currency name (e.g. USD), the second with a conversion pair (e.g. USD-EUR), and a third with the reverse pair (e.g. EUR-USD).

I ran the code below and came up with a list of scraped conversion values in the format:

```
USD, ###, ###
EUR, ###, ###
etc
```

But I don't know how to populate my arrays into thirds. I tried reading the Jsoup API but I'm a complete beginner and haven't been able to make progress today.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
package jsouptest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.x-rates.com/table?from=USD&amount=1").userAgent("Safari/11.0.1").get();

            Elements currency = doc.select("td");

            int i=0;
            for (Element names : currency) {
                i++;
                System.out.println(names.getElementsByTag("td").first().text());
            }            

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JsoupTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hint: `x % 3 == 0` is `true` when `x` is a multiple of 3

Answer (score 0):

The following method will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.x-rates.com/table?from=USD&amount=1").userAgent("Safari/11.0.1").get();

        Elements currency = doc.select("td");

        List<String> currencyNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> toRate = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> fromRate = new ArrayList<>();

        // this crude scraping assumes that the currency table has the following three columns (ordered from left to right):
        //  - the currency name
        //  - the from rate i.e. the number of units of this currency which can be bought by one dollar
        //  - the to rate i.e. the number of dollars which can be bought by one unit of this currency
        for (int i = 0; i < currency.size(); i += 3) {
            currencyNames.add(currency.get(i).text());
            fromRate.add(Double.valueOf(currency.get(i + 1).select("a").text()));
            toRate.add(Double.valueOf(currency.get(i + 2).select("a").text()));
        }

        // this will output something like:
        //  Currency: Euro, From: 0.857234, To: 1.166543
        System.out.println(String.format("Currency: %s, From: %s, To: %s", currencyNames.get(0), fromRate.get(0), toRate.get(0)));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JsoupTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

However, this does make assumptions about the table ordering and about the contents of each column in the table. So, it probably makes sense to add checks e.g. check that the columns `i + 1` and `i + 2` have the corect class and contain a href etc.

Also, the `from` and `to` rates are just the inverse of each other so you might not need to capture both of them. You could instead create a `Map` of currency name vs. 'the number of units of this currency which can be bought by one dollar' (and 'the number of dollars which can be bought by one unit of this currency' can be calculated by the inverse). Here's an example of that approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.x-rates.com/table?from=USD&amount=1").userAgent("Safari/11.0.1").get();

        Elements currency = doc.select("td");
        Map<String, Double> currencyAndRate = new HashMap<>();
        Elements rates = currency.select("td.rtRates");

        for (Element rate : rates) {
            Elements a = rate.select("a");

            String href = a.attr("href");
            String[] split = href.split("=");
            if (!split[2].equals("USD")) {
                String currencyName = split[2];
                Double value = Double.valueOf(a.text());
                currencyAndRate.put(currencyName, value);
            }
        }

        // this will output something like: 0.857234
        System.out.println(currencyAndRate.get("EUR"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JsoupTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Again, you should include checks on each element to ensure that the scraped HTML document matches the code's expectations.